# SAS program with local library in set statement

Tags: sas

I am learning the RSUBMIT newly and I discovered that when I do a rsubmit with data statement, it doesnt take a local libray in the set statement?

How can we process this?

my code

```
signon server;

rsubmit;
data x; 
set loca.mydata ;run;
endrsubmit;
```

this throws error saying

```
ERROR: Libref loca is not assigned.
```

should the set statement dataset also be present in the remote library?

Comment: Hey, if you're happy with the answer please select it as appropriate please, for my benefit and other users looking for a correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

When you rsubmit some code you're basically sending it off elsewhere to get processed meaning none of your local assignments are present on the remote server.

One way to use your "LOCA" library would be to reassign it once you've r-submitted the code:

```
signon server;
rsubmit;
libname LOCA "<path here>";
data x;
set loca.mydata; run;
endrsubmit;
```

A second method would be to share the library between the sessions using inheritlib:

```
signon server;
rsubmit inheritlib=(LOCA=R_LOCA);

data x;
set R_LOCA.mydata; run;
endrsubmit;
```

In the both cases you'll also need to retrieve your dataset "WORK.X" from the remote server.  Both methods I've shown will also allow you to do this.

Comment: Wow.. this inheritlib option is amazing. I dont have to move the data to server. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad the solution worked for you.  You may also wish to look at the macro functions "%syslput" and "%sysrput" which allow you to send and receive macro variables to/from the remote server.  p.s. If the answer above is correct please accept as an answer :)

Comment: Are there any limitations to INHERITLIB - in particular, does the server have to have access to the library via a share, or does SAS/CONNECT download/upload the data?

Comment: There may be some limitations although I've used it extensively and not found any. You can transfer without having any share in place (i.e. a work directory and a permanent SAS area on another box) so I'd assume a SAS connect type transfer happens in the background yes.

Comment: I have the same question,
If I am accessing Oracle database, on the remote server I use the libname to assign a library and then run the program via rsubmit. 

but here with INHERITLIB, i use the local library which has the oracle data accessed, on the remote server, how does this happen? 

Is the direct access of oracle data from the server better or using INHERITLIB effective?

Comment: There is a specfic problem with Oracle DB connections in inheritlib (kb31613) so I can only assume that inheritlib works in the majority of cases and connections but a problem can occur.